# Have to Disable and Enable Adapter Every 60 seconds to use internet

Tags: wireless-networking, wireless-access-point, hotspot, wireless-adapter

I used to have a normal wireless modem that worked perfectly with high speed on my desktop playing PC games online. Now I have a Clear Spot Hot Spot thing, basically a 4G portable hotspot. It surprisingly works fine with everything, except my desktop computer. When I would connect to it using the factory Dell wireless adapter inside, but the internet wouldn't connect in anything. I found out a way to temporarily fix the problem by right clicking the Clear spot network and pressing diagnose, which would say it soled the problem by resetting the wireless access point. I think that is the wireless adapter inside. I read on a forum online that the adapter inside my desktop it probably just not able to work with the Clear Spot. So I went to Best Buy to get a new adapter and ended up buying a 50$ NetGear wireless adapter. Coming home and trying the adapter seemed to have worked fine with a few bumps to connect but I did it. Now a problem showed up and has now bugged me to point of writing this looking help..

About a week ago The pages stopped loading so I tried the same method last time, but it didn't work. I found out a way to fix it again temporarily, I disable and enable the wireless adapter in the (Control Panel\Network and Internet\Network Connections). This worked for a few days but more and more I had to keep doing it. It's now at the point to where I have to do the process just about every 60 seconds...

I'm sure you can see me pain being a PC gamer and can no longer play any Online games. Is There any way to fix this?

P.S. 
      I've noticed that if I tend to stream a movie while nothing else loads, the video with continue to download and stream. Not on YouTube though only Streaming from download websites... like PutLocker

Comment: This does not sound like normal behavior for a good setup.  My best guess, since this has affected multiple network cards, is that the problem is not with your machine's ability to use the network card.  It might be that the network card has a bad connection, and resetting the adapter has the side effect of making the network card try to re-initiate the connection.  You might benefit by trying to improve reception.  Make sure all antennas are oriented the same way (generally vertical).  A NIC with a wire that goes to an external antenna may help.  Buying an 802.11 repeater might be useful.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you might have a wireless encryption issue, you might check the logs of your Hotspot to see your MAC address on your computer is Authenticating and then Deauthenticating. If that is the case you might want to setup another SSID on the hotspot and try changing the encryption to WPA2 (pre shared key) - you said you got a new adaptor, and it should be supported. Then add that network in the control panel to your PC.